# How do I modify an XML element based on XML attribute content in Perl using XML::Simple?

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML of the below format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<outer_tag>
        <inner_tag name="Name_0" template="Template_0">
        <string name="Name_1"><default>DEFAULT_NAME</default></string>
        <string name="Name_2"><default /></string>
        <string name="Name_3"><default></default></string>
        </inner_tag>
</outer_tag>
```

I need to modify the element with content "DEFAULT_NAME" , also, it's parent tag attribute needs to be "Name_1".

So, the output will be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<outer_tag>
        <inner_tag name="Name_0" template="Template_0">
        <string name="Name_1"><default>**NEW_NAME**</default></string>
        <string name="Name_2"><default /></string>
        <string name="Name_3"><default></default></string>
        </inner_tag>
</outer_tag>
```

I tried the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;

my $xml_file = 'xml1.xml';

my $xml = XMLin(
    $xml_file,
    KeepRoot => 1,
    ForceArray => 1,
);

$xml->{outer_tag}->[0]->{string}->[0]->{default} = 'New_Name';

XMLout(
    $xml,
    KeepRoot => 1,
    NoAttr => 1,
    OutputFile => $xml_file,
);
```

But it's adding the New_Name1 at the end, not modifying the one I needed to replace. I'm new to XML in Perl.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. (Hint: the best solution almost certainly doesn't use XML::Simple.)

Comment: Entirely unrelated, but can save you some typing: the `->` is [optional between bracket subscripts](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Arrow-Notation), so you could use this instead: `$xml->{outer_tag}[0]{string}[0]{default} = 'New_Name'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XML::Simple` comes with the [following warning](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#SYNOPSIS):

> PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS MODULE IN NEW CODE

As such, I would suggest to use another module (for instance, [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) or [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)). If you *have to* use `XML::Simple`, see the end of my answer.

With `XML::Twig`, you could do:

```
use XML::Twig;

my $xml_file = 'xml1.xml';
my $twig = XML::Twig->new();
$twig->parsefile($xml_file);

my $node = ($twig->get_xpath('/outer_tag/inner_tag/string[@name="Name_1"]/default'))[0];
$node->set_text('New_Name');

$twig->print;
```

You can indent the output or print to a file if you want, see [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).

Or, using `XML::LibXML`:

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml_file = 'xml1.xml';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $xml_file);

my $node = ($dom->findnodes('/outer_tag/inner_tag/string[@name="Name_1"]/default/text()'))[0];
$node->setData('New_Name');

print $dom->toString
```

---

If you insist on using `XML::Simple`:

The reason your current code with `XML::Simple` is not working is that you assume what the structure of `$xml` is, and your assumption is wrong. With `Data::Dumper` or `Data::Printer`, you can easily check what your structure contains, and the problem becomes obvious:

```
use Data::Printer;

my $xml_file = 'xml1.xml';

my $xml = XMLin(
    $xml_file,
    KeepRoot => 1,
    ForceArray => 1,
    );

p $xml;
```

This will output:

```
\ {
    outer_tag   [
        [0] {
            inner_tag   {
                Name_0   {
                    string     {
                        Name_1   {
                            default   [
                                [0] "DEFAULT_NAME"
                            ]
                        },
....
```

It thus becomes obvious that you should have done

```
$xml->{outer_tag}->[0]->{inner_tag}->{Name_0}->{string}->{Name_1}->{default} = 'New_Name';
```

instead of

```
$xml->{outer_tag}->[0]->{string}->[0]->{default} = 'New_Name';
```

That being said, use `XML::Twig` or `XML::LibXML`.

Comment: I tried the XML::LibXML and got the below error: `Can't call method "setData" on an undefined value at test_xml.pl line 7.` am I missing something ?

Comment: @sbk It works when I run it with the input you provided. My guess is that your input file is not what you pasted in the question. I can't help you without knowing the actual structure of your data.

Comment: Looks like it's an environment issue. Thanks for solution. does it not replace the existing file ?

Comment: @sbk the snippets I provided do not replace the existing file, but you can `open` it and print to it. For instance, `open my $FH, '>', $xml_file`, then for `XML::LibXML`, a simple `print $FH $dom->toString` will work. For `XML::Twig`, you can do `$xml->print($FH)`.